# Reanimating a creature with undying

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A creature with undying has already come back to the battlefield due to its ability (and gained the +1/+1) dies again. [Raise Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRaise%20Dead%5d) is cast and once more returns that creature to the hand, which is then summoned again. Is its undying "reset", or does he still have that +1/+1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not have a +1/+1 counter.

---

We never actually move an object from one zone to another. Instead, we create a new object in the new zone and the old one ceases to exist.<sup>[CR 400.7]</sup> Any counters on the old object ceases to exist along with it.<sup>[CR 121.2]</sup>

That means the card in the graveyard (a new object) doesn't have the original +1/+1 counter. If you use Raise Dead to return that card to your hand, the card in your hand (yet another object) won't have the original +1/+1 counter. And finally, if you cast that card from your hand, the new creature (a fourth object) won't have the original +1/+1 counter.

But does it gain a new +1/+1 counter from undying when you recast the creature card after getting it back from the graveyard using Raise Dead? No. Undying is a triggered ability that triggers when a permanent with Undying is placed into a graveyard.<sup>[CR 702.92a]</sup> It is not triggered when a card with Undying is cast from your hand, so it doesn't add any counters in that situation.

---

> 121.2. Counters on an object are not retained if that object moves from one zone to another. The counters are not “removed”; they simply cease to exist. See rule 400.7.
>
> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are nine exceptions to this rule:
>
> 702.92a Undying is a triggered ability. “Undying” means “When this permanent is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, if it had no +1/+1 counters on it, return it to the battlefield under its owner’s control with a +1/+1 counter on it.”

Answer (score 3):

Counters are always removed from creatures when they die (unless they specifically say otherwise, like [Skullbriar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=236485)). Same if they change zones in any other way, whether they're exiled, returned to your hand, or put in your library.

> 121.2. Counters on an object are not retained if that object moves from one zone to another. The counters are not “removed”; they simply cease to exist. See rule 400.7.

So when this creature dies the second time, the +1/+1 counter is removed, and now it's sitting in your graveyard, with no counters. Raise Dead brings it back, still with no counters. (And now if it were to die *again*, then Undying would bring it back with a +1/+1 counter again.)

For the sake of completion, though it's not necessary here, the additional rule mentioned above is:

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are nine exceptions to this rule: [...]

That's a good general thing to keep in mind: if something has died and been brought back, it doesn't remember anything about how it was before, whether it's counters or something else.